# HLSL: Enforce Constant Register Limit at Compile Time

Tags: xna, shader, hlsl, vertex-shader

In HLSL, is there any way to limit the number of constant registers that the compiler uses?

Specifically, if I have something like:

```
float4 foobar[300];
```

In a vs_2_0 vertex shader, the compiler will merrily generate the effect with more than 256 constant registers. But a 2.0 vertex shader is only guaranteed to have access to 256 constant registers, so when I try to use the effect, it fails in an obscure and GPU-dependent way at runtime. I would much rather have it fail at compile time.

This problem is especially annoying as the compiler itself allocates constant registers behind the scenes, on top of the ones I am asking for. I have to check the assembly to see if I'm over the limit.

Ideally I'd like to do this in HLSL (I'm using the XNA content pipeline), but if there's a flag that can be passed to the compiler that would also be interesting.

Comment: Good question. I would also post it on http://forums.xna.com/forums/27.aspx since the DirectX developers are hanging on there.

Comment: Thanks, Stringer Bell. I posted it to the XNA forum as you suggested: http://forums.xna.com/forums/p/53856/326864.aspx

Comment: Also: if there's no way to do it in HLSL or with the compiler, is there any way to count the number of constant registers a compiled shader uses programmatically? (Ideally using XNA)

Comment: Maybe look at ShaderCompiler.Disassemble method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Stringer Bell's pointing out of the Disassemble method, I have whipped up a small post-build utility to parse and check the effect. Be warned that this is not very pretty. It is designed for XNA 3.1 and requires the `ServiceContainer` and `GraphicsDeviceService` classes from [the XNA WinForms sample](http://creators.xna.com/en-US/sample/winforms_series1). Pass a content directory path on the command line with no trailing slash.

```
class Program
{
    const int maxRegisters = 256; // Sutiable for VS 2.0, not much else
    static int retval = 0;
    static string root;
    static ContentManager content;

    static void CheckFile(string path)
    {
        string name = path.Substring(root.Length+1, path.Length - (root.Length+1) - @".xnb".Length);
        Effect effect;
        try { effect = content.Load<Effect>(name); }
        catch { return; } // probably not an Effect
        string effectSource = effect.Disassemble(false);

        int highest = -1; // highest register allocated

        var matches = Regex.Matches(effectSource, @" c([0-9]+)"); // quick and dirty
        foreach(Match match in matches)
        {
            int register = Int32.Parse(match.Groups[1].ToString());
            if(register > highest)
                highest = register;
        }

        var parameters = Regex.Matches(effectSource, @"^ *// *[a-zA-Z_0-9]+ +c([0-9]+) +([0-9]+)", RegexOptions.Multiline);
        foreach(Match match in parameters)
        {
            int register = Int32.Parse(match.Groups[1].ToString()) + Int32.Parse(match.Groups[2].ToString()) - 1;
            if(register > highest)
                highest = register;
        }

        if(highest+1 > maxRegisters)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: Shader \"" + name + "\" uses " + (highest+1).ToString() + " constant registers, which is TOO MANY!");
            retval = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Shader \"" + name + "\" uses " + (highest+1).ToString() + " constant registers (OK)");
        }
    }

    static void CheckDirectory(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach(string file in Directory.GetFiles(path, @"*.xnb"))
                CheckFile(file);
            foreach(string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
                CheckDirectory(dir);
        }
        catch { return; } // Don't care
    }

    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        root = args[0];

        Form form = new Form(); // Dummy form for creating a graphics device
        GraphicsDeviceService gds = GraphicsDeviceService.AddRef(form.Handle,
                form.ClientSize.Width, form.ClientSize.Height);

        ServiceContainer services = new ServiceContainer();
        services.AddService<IGraphicsDeviceService>(gds);
        content = new ContentManager(services, root);

        CheckDirectory(root);

        return retval;
    }
}
```